# Циклическая работа

Tags: jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток.

Есть код:

```
jQuery('.one').on('click', '.del',function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var delId = jQuery(this).siblings('.theId').val();/* получет id*/
    var sesID = jQuery('#sessionId').val();/*получает дентификатор пользователя*/
        jQuery.post("/script/script.php",
            {id:delId,
            session:sesID},
        function(dataS) {
            jQuery("#theDiv").html(dataS) ;
            jQuery('.one').on('click', '.del',function(e){
                var thisis= jQuery(this);
                delCart(e,thisis,sesID);});
    });
```

Суть в том, что при отработке ajax заново идет построение dom элиментов. А ссылка с классом del находится в заменяемом скрипте, участке, к примеру:

```
<div class="one">1<a href="#" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="one">2<a href="#" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="one">3<a href="#" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="one">4<a href="#" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="one">5<a href="#" class="del">x</a></div>
<div class="one">6<a href="#" class="del">x</a></div>
```

При работе скрипта каждый див удаляется (через взаимодествие с базой данных), здесь я поставил двойную отработку кода. Но, как вы понимаете, мне надо, чтобы код отрабатывал такое количество раз, сколько пользователь будет нажимать на ссылку с классом del. Не подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.del',function(ev){
    ...
    jQuery.post("/script/script.php",
        {id:delId, session:sesID},
    function(dataS) {
        jQuery("#theDiv").html(dataS) ;
});
```

**Правка:**

Ещё раз, с пояснением.

Есть родительский элемент, вешаем на него обработчик клика на любую сабноду с классом one.

При изменении содержимого родительского элемента обработчик никуда не делся и предсказуемо сработает при следующем нажатии.

```
<div class="theDiv">
   <div class="one">1<a href="#" class="del">x</a></div>
   <div class="one">2<a href="#" class="del">x</a></div>
</div>

$('.theDiv').on('click', '.del',function(ev){
    var delId = $(this).siblings('.theId').val();
    var sesID = $('#sessionId').val();
    $.post("/script/script.php", {id:delId, session:sesID})
       .done(function(dataS) {
            $(".theDiv").html(dataS) ;
       })
       .fail(function(){ ... });
});
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, почему я ввел вот эту часть кода

    " jQuery('.one').on('click', '.del',function(e){
                    var thisis= jQuery(this);
                    delCart(e,thisis,sesID);});"

?

Навреное, потому,  что без него он второй раз не отрабатывает, отрабытывает цикличиски.

Comment: @Sergalas, вот вы зря сейчас. Посмотрите документацию по `.on()`.

Comment: Etki  в том то и прикол, что я пробовал. Неужели думаете, я не попробовал с певого через .on запустить, не отрабытыват. Один раз работает. И все дописываешь

    " jQuery('.one').on('click', '.del',function(e){ var thisis= jQuery(this); delCart(e,thisis,sesID);});"

И второй раз работает, на третий все не работает.

Comment: @Sergalas, еще раз: неважно, что там пробовалось, эта конструкция работает, **если ее повесить на body**. Это гарантирую лично я, это гарантирует отсутствие буквы "ы" в слове пробовал, это гарантируют правила тся/ться.

Comment: Все, реально понял, в чем затыка, спасибо, что разъяснили, вот вам ещё и плюс за объяснения и мои тупки. :)

Comment: Etki, я же уже отписался, что понял. :)